# What is the significance of currentStyle

Tags: java, javascript, css, jakarta-ee, aem

Can you tell me in `CQ5`, the exact use of `currentStyle`.

I have one line like

`int absParent = currentStyle.get("absParent", 3);`

May I know what currentStyle will do here.

Comment: It would seem that it is getting the current style from it's parent element. The current style is a variable that is assigned different values as and when.

Comment: Thanks Vector,that means it is working in the same way as properties.get(), but it provides the values stored for the property absParent from your design instead of the currentPage,thanks again

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `currentStyle`, an instance of the [Style](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/ref/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/designer/Style.html) class contains the properties that reflect the design aspect of a cell.

Any change to the properties of a component in design mode, gets saved under `/etc/designs/<<your project design>>` (in case the `cq:design` property is available for the page or in any of its parent) or `/etc/designs/default` (the default design), unlike the properties authored in an ordinary dialog, in which case the values are stored under the same page.

Thus, the `currentStyle.get()`, functions similar to `properties.get()` as it extends [ValueMap](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/ref/javadoc/org/apache/sling/api/resource/ValueMap.html), just that it provides you the values stored in the design instead of the content.

There isn't much information available related to this in the docs. However you can take a look at the [Designer](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/components.html#Logo%20Component) to understand it further.

Comment: Thanks Rakhi, it is a new thing for me.Nice to know this

Comment: It would be nice to have the source or link to documentation for future reference.

Answer (score 3):

In simple plain words currentStyle.get() is used when you want to get data from design_dialog and properties.get() is used when you are getting it from a dialog.

Note: data in design_dialog is global for the template, which means you can access it anywhere in the template by just using currentStyle.get() and you don't need to setAttribute(), where as in dialog the data is stored locally in the page properties.